# Input data given to 'points' is not a valid GeoJSON object

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I want to populate some of the cooridnates what I get from the back end on mapbox map below is my sample json what I receive from backend

```
[
  {
    "model": "bike_parking_info.bikeparkinginfo",
    "pk": 13561,
    "fields": {
      "start_station_id": 3276,
      "start_station_name": "Marin Light Rail",
      "start_station_latitude": "40.71458403535893",
      "start_station_longitude": "-74.04281705617905",
      "end_station_id": 3256,
      "end_station_name": "Pier 40 - Hudson River Park",
      "end_station_latitude": "40.7277140777778",
      "end_station_longitude": "-74.01129573583603"
    }
  }
]
```

I have around 1200 objects to load from back end with coordinates
I am iterating it over below loop

```
let result = []
        data.forEach(function (data1, index) {
            //console.log(data1['fields']);
            var jsonData={
               //  feature for Mapbox DC
                'type': 'Feature',
                'geometry': {
                  'type': 'Point',
                  'coordinates': [
                    Number(data1['fields']['start_station_longitude']),
                    Number(data1['fields']['start_station_latitude']),
                  ]
                },
                'properties': {
                  'title': data1['fields']['start_station_name']
                }
              }
              result.push(jsonData);


export const mapDetails = state => state.getInfo.features;
```

this is how I am populating on UI

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: mapContainer.current,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
      center: [-96, 37.8],
      zoom: 3
    });

    map.on('load', function () {
      // Add an image to use as a custom marker
      map.loadImage(
        'https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/custom_marker.png',
        function (error, image) {
          if (error) throw error;
          map.addImage('custom-marker', image);
          // Add a GeoJSON source with 2 points
          map.addSource('points', {
            'type': 'geojson',
            'data': {
              'type': 'FeatureCollection',
              'features': **mapDetails**
            }
          });

          // Add a symbol layer
          map.addLayer({
            'id': 'points',
            'type': 'symbol',
            'source': 'points',
            'layout': {
              'icon-image': 'custom-marker',
              // get the title name from the source's "title" property
              'text-field': ['get', 'title'],
              'text-font': [
                'Open Sans Semibold',
                'Arial Unicode MS Bold'
              ],
              'text-offset': [0, 1.25],
              'text-anchor': 'top'
            }
          });
        }
      );
    });
```

but I am getting below errors constantly

```
 "Input data given to 'points' is not a valid GeoJSON object."
```

please help me out here what is going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I got my fault I had to use **useSelector**  to retrieve data back to my UI so had to make below changes

```
let dataToDisplay = useSelector(mapDetails);
```